# import multiple line textfile

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, datarow

I have a textfile as shown in the image, I need to import this file into a table 
[image]

but I need it in this format

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for telling us, and good luck. If you get stuck, don't forget to provide us with consumable sample data and expected results, shows us what you've tried, explain why it isn't working and *importantly* **ask a question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Notepad++ (for example) you can replace ",Employee Ref:" and "Stop:" with an empty character. Then there's an Edit -> Trim Trailing Space menu to erase unnecessary spaces.
Normally you will get this :

> 626819 No  1000 Yes  1001 No...

Then you can replace " " with ","
You will get this :

> 626819,No,,1000,Yes,,1001,No...

Then using the extended search mode you can replace ",," with "\n" to make a CSV file.
You will get this :

```
626819,No
1000,Yes
1001,No
```

Finally you just have to add the titles like this :

```
Employee Ref,Stop    
626819,No
1000,Yes
1001,No
```